# Como pasar un if a un operador terniario?

Tags: java, java-8

Hola me gustaria saber como puedo pasar este if a un operador terniario

```
if(parameterIn.get("amount")!=null
                && util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue()))
                        ||parameterIn.get("amount")== null){
        }else{
            this.addAdvice(Constants.MGBD100005.getValue());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis básica del operador ternario es esta: (condición) ? expr1 : expr2

```
(condicion) 
  ? ejecutarCodigoQueDeseasSiLaCondicionSeCumple() // El signo ? separa las condiciones del código a ejecutar cuando la condición es true
  : ejecutarCodigoEnCasoQueLaCondicionNoSeCumpla() // El signo : separa el bloque donde colocarías el código del else
 (Está identado así para que sea más fácil de ver)
```

En tu caso sería algo así:

```
parameterIn.get("amount")!=null && util.validateAmount((double) parameterIn.get(Constants.AMOUNT.getValue())) ||parameterIn.get("amount")== null 
    ? ejecutarCodigoQueDeseasSiLaCondicionSeCumple() // No colocaste código para que se ejecutara, pero luego lo colocas tú. 
    : this.addAdvice(Constants.MGBD100005.getValue()); // Else
```

Fuentes:

[Operador condicional (ternario) Manual Web](https://www.manualweb.net/java/operadores-condicionales-java/#:%7E:text=El%20operador%20ternario%20se%20suele,vble1%3Avble2%3B%20System.)

[Operador Ternario Línea de Código](https://lineadecodigo.com/java/el-operador-ternario-en-java/)

Comment: Justo eso iba a preguntar, sobre la flecha que pones! pero ya lo arregle de todas formas quedo bien, muchas gracias!